# Zorder specification in matplotlib patch collections?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a series of rectangles and circles, with the circles in the foreground.

According to the following post, I have to set the zorder argument:
[Patches I add to my graph are not opaque with alpha=1. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390699/patches-i-add-to-my-graph-are-not-opaque-with-alpha-1-why)

This works fine when I plot all the circles individually, but not when I try to place a series of circles into a collection and add the collection, i.e.

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)
p_fancy = FancyBboxPatch((1,1),
                         0.5, 0.5,
                         boxstyle="round,pad=0.1",
                         fc='beige',
                         ec='None', zorder=1)
ax.add_patch(p_fancy)
ax.set_xlim([0,2])
ax.set_ylim([0,2])
circ=patches.Circle ((1,1), 0.2, zorder=10)
ax.add_patch(circ)
```

works fine:
[image]
while

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)
p_fancy = FancyBboxPatch((1,1),
                         0.5, 0.5,
                         boxstyle="round,pad=0.1",
                         fc='beige',
                         ec='None', zorder=1)
ax.add_patch(p_fancy)
ax.set_xlim([0.,2])
ax.set_ylim([0.,2])
circ=[]
circ.append(patches.Circle ((1,1), 0.2, zorder=10))
coll=PatchCollection(circ)
ax.add_collection(coll)
```

does not:

[image]
Is there a reason, or does zorder work differently with patch collections in ways that I don't understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case you want the `PatchCollection` to have a defined zorder, not the members of the `PatchCollection`. Thus, you need to specify zorder for the collection.

```
circ=[]
circ.append(Circle ((1,1), 0.2))
coll=PatchCollection(circ, zorder=10)
ax.add_collection(coll)
```