# Matplotlib to plot hundreds of Rectangle contours

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph

I want to plot a few Rectangle outlines using matplotlib. The thing is, I need tons of them, so the "normal" way of drawing rectangles is pretty slow. I solved this using [How to speed up plot...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905305/how-to-speed-up-the-plot-of-a-large-number-of-rectangles-with-matplotlib). The thing is, I am not able anymore to just plot the edge of the rectangles using `fill=None` or `edgecolor=...` and `facecolor=None`.

See a toy example of my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


def plot_rectangle_from_area(area, color):
    """Plot a rectangle for a given area with color"""
    return Rectangle(xy=(area["min_x"], area["min_y"]), width=area["max_x"] - area["min_x"],
                     height=area["max_y"] - area["min_y"],
                     fill=None)  #  linewidth=0, edgecolor=color, facecolor=None, zorder=100, alpha=0, 


sample_areas = [{"min_x": -1, "max_x": 0.4, "min_y": 0.7, "max_y": 1},
                {"min_x": 0.5, "max_x": 1, "min_y": 0.1, "max_y": 0.5}]
rectangles = []

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ... print some contour via meshgrid

if sample_areas:
    for area_i in sample_areas:
        rectangles.append(plot_rectangle_from_area(area_i, color="r"))
#   ... some more cases

# Append the rectangles all at once instead of on their own, see:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905305/how-to-speed-up-the-plot-of-a-large-number-of-rectangles-with-matplotlib
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(rectangles))

# ... legend, save, grid, ...
plt.show()
```

At first I create a array for all the Rectangles, the append to it and use PatchCollection to plot it [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905305/how-to-speed-up-the-plot-of-a-large-number-of-rectangles-with-matplotlib). The following example does exactly the same, just without the PatchCollection and is working fine.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


def plot_rectangle_from_area(area, color):
    """Plot a rectangle from given area"""
    return Rectangle(xy=(area["min_x"], area["min_y"]), width=area["max_x"] - area["min_x"],
                     height=area["max_y"] - area["min_y"],
                     fill=None)  #  linewidth=0, edgecolor=color, facecolor=None, zorder=100, alpha=0, 

sample_areas = [{"min_x": -1, "max_x": 0.4, "min_y": 0.7, "max_y": 1},
                {"min_x": 0.5, "max_x": 1, "min_y": 0.1, "max_y": 0.5}]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

if sample_areas:
    for area_i in sample_areas:
        ax.add_patch(plot_rectangle_from_area(area_i, color="r"))
plt.show()
```

Here are some plots I created with both of these codes. On the left the wished result using the slow method, on the right the result I get with PatchCollection:

[image]
[image]

I tried multiple combinations of fill, edgecolor, facecolor and even the suggestion with zorder from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390699/patches-i-add-to-my-graph-are-not-opaque-with-alpha-1-why).

Is it possible to use the "fast" way of creating rectangles and have just the borders shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - looking at the documentation for [PatchCollection](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection),  there is a parameter called `match_original`, which - when `True` - will set the properties of the patches to match those of the original rectangles.

So simply change

```
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(rectangles))
```

to

```
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(rectangles, match_original=True))
```

Comment: Thank you, that was easy. Seems like i overlooked that parameter. Works for me